# How to adjust this query to get the result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which is actually a members match with initial letter 'a' and the result also contain users friend.
What I would like is that the users friend must come before in the result and then remaining users.

Here is the query

```
SELECT `a`.`mem_id` 
    FROM `members` `a` 
    INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT `n2`.`mem_id` 
            FROM `network` `n1`,`network` `n2` 
            WHERE `n1`.`frd_id` = `n2`.`mem_id` 
                AND `n1`.`mem_id`='777' 
                AND `n2`.`frd_id`='777'
        ) `b` 
    WHERE `a`.`mem_id`=`b`.`mem_id` 
        AND `a`.`profilenam` LIKE 'a%' 
        AND `a`.`deleted` ='N' 
    ORDER BY `profilenam`
```

Comment: It sounds like the query is actually returning the correct rows, just not in the order you want, is that right?

Comment: You could make an example on sqlfiddle and post the link in your question? then we can see it in action and more easely explain why it's not doing what you want.

Comment: @MattB. yes i thought it but i didnt find way to arrange it in proper

Comment: Can you give sample table data?

Comment: I meant some sample table data so I can help you with the query?

Comment: Use this => http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: *If* you're only getting one member and his/her friends at a time, it might be better to run 2 separate queries, one for the member and another for the member's friends.

Comment: @MattB. that will take time bcoz then i need to merge these two which will take time

Comment: If your database library has a function to turn a database result into an array then it could be as simple as `array_merge`, especially since it seems all you're retrieving are member IDs, unless you left the other fields out of the SELECT query in your example.

Comment: Does this query actually return members who are not friends of user `777`? As far as I can understand, the subquery returns only friends. And since the results of the subquery are **inner**-joined to `members`, the final output can contain *only* friends. The list is filtered down to those matching additional conditions, but nothing is *added* to it, so the remaining members are still friends of `777`. Am I missing something? How can this query return non-friends?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question, here is a query that will return the data you're looking for:

```
SELECT M.mem_id
FROM members M
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT N1.mem_id
                     ,N1.frd_id
                 FROM network N1
                 INNER JOIN network N2 ON N2.mem_id = N1.frd_id
                                          AND N2.frd_id = N1.mem_id) F ON F.mem_id = M.mem_id
                                                                         AND F.frd_id = '777'
WHERE M.profilename LIKE 'a%'
    AND M.deleted = 'N'
ORDER BY CASE
            WHEN F.mem_id IS NOT NULL THEN 0
            ELSE 1
         END, M.profilename
```

**Some explanation about my query:**

The table `members` has a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on a query that returns every existing friendships (based on your query, i supposed that to consider two members as friends it's mandatory to have a two ways connection in table `network`).

This jointure with the condition `F.frd_id = '777` ensure that the join is only made if the active member is a friend of the member with id `'777'`.

The last element is the key element that you were looking for, the `ORDER BY` clause to have the friends first and then the other members. The first condition of the clause is a simple `SWITCH` statement that tests if the jointure exists or not, if yes that means that the member is a friend, otherwise not. Every friends have the value 0 and the other members have the value 1, by doing an ascending sort on this value the result will be ordered as desired.

Hope this will help.